# Add Cloudwatch logging to AmplifyGraphqlApi

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-appsync

Typescript CdK 2 question...

The AmplifyGraphqlApi construct in `@aws-amplify/graphql-api-construct` is a relatively new way to set up an AppSync endpoint for an Amplify application.  Something that got lost when I made a recent migration from the older `GraphqlApi` construct (from  `@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha`) is Cloudwatch logging.  How do I add Cloudwatch logging to a AmplifyGraphqlApi instance?